# intersection of line and circle with different slope

Tags: matlab, line, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Circle line collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-collision-detection)

Can anyone suggest how to find the intersection point of line and circle.

```
theta=0:.01:2*pi;

x1=4*cos(theta)+4;

y1=4*sin(theta)+4;

x=[0 1 3 5 8]

y=[0 1 1 3 3]

for i=2:length(x)    

    s(i)=(y(i)-y(i-1))/(x(i)-x(i-1));

end

s

inter=y

plot([x],[y],x1,y1,'-')

axis([0 10 0 10])
```

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=intersect+line+circle

Comment: I did the coding from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ but it is not correct

Comment: is there anyother way to do from the above code?

Comment: What you have there is a polyline, not a straight line. This is an entirely different problem

Comment: There seems to be some difference between what you are asking and what you have in your code. I think you really need to provide an image or a link to an image that SHOWS what you mean without ambiguity.

Comment: Is there anyway to solve this problem?? The other code is a big one. I cannot upload

Comment: A circle and a line can have at most 2 intersection points. You have described a polyline with your code above. This is a very different problem as there can be many intersections. you need to decide what you mean - a straight line or a polyline??

Comment: for now can you please suggest for a polyline. and for straight line I did some coding but I have some doubts regarding that but I don't know how to explain it unless I can post a picture here. So , can you please do for polyline? thanks

Comment: If this is what you want you should edit your question to make it clear.