# Intersection of circle and line

Tags: matlab, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Circle line collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-collision-detection)

How do I find the intersection of a circle and a line (not straight) with different slope.

The points for the line is shown below:

theta=0:.01:2*pi;

x1=5*cos(theta)+4;

y1=5*cos(theta)+1;

```
x=[1 1 4 7 7 8 8 8]
y=[2 3 3 3 5 8 8 8]
```

And also, how do I calculate the length of this line?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Are the only questions you're ever going to ask here about the [intersection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11510330) of [circles](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11508932) and [lines](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11494878)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a polyline, use the mathematical formula contained [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html) on each individual straight line segment of your polyline. You have asked this question before so you should be able to do it for a single line segment. All you need to to is break your polyline into its constituent parts and solve the problem for each one and store the intersection points.